# Send Image to channel if # of reactions is reached, Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a function where if an image a user sent gets a certain amount of upvotes, the bot will send that image to another channel. The code I have right now works, except that it sends the image that received the needed # of upvotes *AND* previous images that have also gotten the needed # of upvotes.

Let's say User A sends an image. That image gets 2 upvotes, and is sent to channel #upvoted-images. User B comes along, and posts an image. Their image also gets 2 upvotes, and is sent to #upvoted-images, but User A's image is sent again, along with User B's image.

```js
bot.on("message", async message => {

  if(message.channel.id !== '869294795019923486')return;
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  message.react("⭐")

  bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
      let limit = 2; // number of thumbsdown reactions you need
      if (reaction.emoji.name == '⭐' && reaction.count >= limit){
          const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'test3');
          message.react("")
          channel.send("My Bot's message", {files:[message.attachments.first().url]});

          console.log(message.attachments.url)
      }
  })

})
```

I'm sort of at a roadblock now, any help's appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify your problem and add more details? How do you expect the code to work? What is your desired behavior? What I understand so far is that when the image gets for example 3 upvotes, it gets sent again to the #test3 channel and so on for 4 upvotes, etc. Is that correct? You want it to be sent only once and when it reaches the 2 votes threshold?

Comment: Sorry! I ran out of time, but I can explain it in depth now. So pretty much, let's say User A sends an image. That image gets 2 upvotes, and is sent to channel #upvoted-images. User B comes along, and posts an image. Their image also gets 2 upvotes, and is sent to #upvoted-images, but User A's image is sent again, along with User B's image.

Comment: @washingm I think it would be useful if you add this description to your question

Comment: @washingm The code you provided is responsible for sending only **one** image. This is not where the problem lies. We need more context, where is the code executed?

Comment: Also your `console.log(message.attachments.url)` always prints `undefined`, because [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) has no property `.url`. You probably meant `console.log(message.attachments.first().url)` as you have above.

Comment: Apologies, the code is located in index.js under a 'bot.on("message", async message' function, Editing the post to include the rest of it. I'm assuming it's sending the previous images as well because they all meet the needed criteria of 2 reactions, so when another image gets to that number, it resubmits the previous images since they all still reach the # of reactions

Comment: Edit: I actually found a way around this. When the image reaches the needed # of reactions, the bot will delete it from the channel, and send it to a different one, in a sense cutting and pasting it. This will help avoid sending the previous images that had reached the # of reactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new event listener every time a message is sent. Each listener callback for `messageReactionAdd` in your case has a reference to the original `message` object. Meaning that when the event triggers, it will trigger for each message the event listener was registered for.

The solution is to bring the event listener for `messageReactionAdd` outside of the event listener for `message`.

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.channel.id !== "869294795019923486") return;
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    message.react("⭐");
});
```

```js
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {

    const message = reaction.message;

    // You could use your  reaction for a neat safety check,
    // so images that were already sent to the channel don't get sent again.
    // We treat  reaction as an indication that the bot has already sent the image to the specified channel.
    // This way when someone unreacts and adds the reaction back,
    // or when someone adds the reaction after it met the two upvote treshold,
    // it won't get sent again.
    if (message.reactions.cache.some(re => re.emoji.name === "" && re.users.cache.has(client.user.id))) {
        return;
    }

    let upvoteLimit = 2;
    // Number of reactions needed to be cast by the users (including the bot itself)
    // in order for the image to be sent to another channel.
    
    if (reaction.emoji.name == "⭐" && reaction.count >= upvoteLimit) {
        const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "test3");
        channel.send("My Bot's message", {files:[message.attachments.first().url]});
        message.react("");
    }

});
```

Note that this only works for images that were sent when the bot was online. If you want it to work for older images, you might want to take a look at [partials](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html).

If you want to collect the reactions only temporarily, you can take a look at [`ReactionCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector).

Comment: Thank you so much, after tweaking that code a little to match my project, it looks like it works! I believe I tried the thumbs up indication before, but possibly put it in the incorrect spot, I appreciate the help and the in depth answer!